# Lightning Experience Bug: Picklist Color Values for Lightning Dashboards not working (UPDATE: fixed in Spring 18!)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, dashboard, bug, report-chart

**Update**

*This issue I've originally found in Winter 17 seems not fixed in Winter 18 release. However the issue does not affect Report Charts based on Opportunity.StageName - but on Custom Objects it's perfectly reproducible.*

**Original Question**

Colors have crucial meanings in processes, e.g. lost- or bad things must be drawn more red alike in contrast to won- or good things which are expected to take shades of green. There is practically no room for discussion with users and clients on this point. There is a high risk of bad business decisions made on wrong colors in charts, because the information can be misleading and the processes become error prone.

I have defined custom colors for pick-list values like this

[image]

*Hint: In this particular example I have to use gray for "Lost" an need a gradient from pink to green on the status progression. But my issue is of general nature.*

Now in Aloha the chart is taking these colors perfectly as expected and shown here:

[image]

But now in lightning I've tried the same by putting the exact same report as  Report Charts on the homepage. Unfortunately, this component ignores the color setting and draws it's own automatically assigned colors over my carefully selected manual color definition. It looks like this:

[image]

**The fact that Lost becomes green is absolutely not acceptable for my use case.**

Now I also tried it with Dashboards, but again without luck and the color mess is basically the same:

[image]

Strangely, if you go to reports and open up the report in LEX, the chart is drawn using the correct color definitions (as expected and as everywhere in Aloha)

[image]

**Questions**

- Is there a way to make the new Lightning Dashboards or any Report- or Chart- component use my manual color definition?
- Is there any other option to enforce colors in an other way on any Lightning Chart without coding my own charting components for that?
- Is this simply a missing feature in LEX? If so: is it one the roadmap to be improved? Any safeharbor-timeline? I ask, because I need to make a decision whether to take care of the drawing myself an write my own charting compo or if waiting is an option. I would clearly prefer a Standard solution without 3rd party stuff or own implementations.

---

**Appendix 1**

If you use many Report Chart Components on one single Flexipage, the automatic coloring is calculated per each Component separately, which makes the whole situation even worse: on one chart Status=Calculation is rendered brown on another blue and on the last in cyan. This is a total mess-up and no one will make any sense out of it:

[image]

**Appendix 2**

The color assignment is the same in LEX setup than it is in Aloha setup (reviewed as crmprodev suggestet)

[image]

**Appendix 3**

I found that this issue at least does not exist for Standard Opportunity StageName. Report-Charts based on that field, will get their colors perfectly rendered in LEX:

[image]

However this seems to be an ongoing flaw on custom objects, possibly on custom picklists on standard objects or other standard fields might be affected, too.

Comment: Looks like you have found an area which Salesforce missed to care. Now this is a bug. I think bug tag should be added to the question.

Comment: @Ashwani as you suggested I added the bug-tag. If anyone feels that this is not a bug but something else: please feel free to remove that tag again.

Comment: I agree with @Ashwani. I think you should report this as a bug Uwe & will delete my answer.

Comment: I never understood the importance of color to users until in the med field we changed the color on the packaging of our products and nurses started using wrong products despite clear labels. Issue, they used "the green one" and had no other association other than color. But I digress. Hope you get this on the squash list

Comment: @Eric sure thing: colors are crucial. It's a brain thing. Human brains operate in the following order of processing: 1. movement, 2. color, 3. text/glyphs. So color-information will always trump labels (at least one of my professors told me so some years ago)

Comment: Imagine if stop lights just showed the words Go, Slow, Stop without any color.....You professor makes sense at least

Comment: Spring 16 help with this? 
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_rd_charts.htm

Comment: @Troy this issue isn't addressed directly in the release notes. However I hadn't had a chance to check that in a pre-release environment.

Comment: This issue still exists in Spring 17. Now hoping for Summer 17.

Comment: This issue still exists in Summer 17 with no improvement. Now hoping for Winter 18.

Comment: This issue still exists in Winter 18. Now hoping for Spring 18.

Answer (score 3):

I was very happy to see, that in Spring 18 this issue seems to be resolved by Salesforce. There was no need to change anything on my end - it just works now on any Orgs I've checked so far - and looks awesome!

[image]

Thanks Salesforce for fixing this!